# Setting Width on a Column Series: Using dotNetCharting

Tags: c#, .net, css, templates, charts

I need to set a static width of a bar chart series using dotNetCharting. My Graph has three series collections of line, spline, and column type. I would just like to set a static width for all series of column type.

I've tried using:

```
myChart.DefaultAxis.StaticColumnWidth = 10;
```

But the .DefaultAxis property isn't valid in intellisense for the whole chart **nor** the Column series collection. Do the series have to be added with data first before setting this?

Also, I've tried adding properties in the series object, no luck.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
series["PixelPointWidth"] = "your value for width";
```

- part of chart series collection: a **custom property**

Comment: Thanks, this was very useful for me.  Microsoft seem to call it a 'custom property' here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456764(VS.100).aspx

Comment: @Bryan no problem, you would think it's a standard requirement

Answer (score 1):

chart1.Series["Series1"]["PixelPointWidth"] = "1";