# Scaling Bar Chart Height With Data

Tags: c#, asp.net, bar-chart

I am using the Microsoft Chart Control.

I am trying to adjust the height of the chart area programmatically. Depending on the rows. Because the Microsoft Chart control requires a height, which cannot be in percentages, nor Auto. Depending on the selected query, the chart can have 1 bar or it can have 100's. This is why I need to adjust the height because bigger data sets appear squished and not readable.

What I have tried is adding a counter `heightCounter` which is the number of bars on the chart.

```
        int newHeight = (heightCounter * 10);

        // Maximum height aloud on Chart Control
        if (newHeight > 32767)
            newHeight = 32767;

        Chart1.Height = newHeight;
```

This sometimes works O.K. with smaller data sets
[image]

but when I have very large datasets the title looks very spaced out because the height is too large.

[image]

Is there a proper way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the way you are approaching the problem is along the right lines, taking a count of the number of series' in the datasource in order to obtain a proportional height.

However, I would be inclined to declare the width of each bar as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10451126/4210193). This would give you more control than using a static multiplier such as the 10 you have.

I would also be inclined to set the height permanently as the calculated height, unless of course the minimum height is a desired feature.

Also, as a side note, isnt increasing by 10 for each quite significant? Have you tried halving that? If I remember rightly, the width of the bars will autmatically scale themselves (if not specifically declared by you).

Comment: Even if I lower the static multiplier to the point where the bars are mashed together, their is still a gigantic space between the title and the chart area.